# Regex for matching a character, but not when it's enclosed in square bracket

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Input string:

```
[Wsg-Fs]-A-A-A-Cgbs-Sg7-[Wwg+s-Fs]-A-A-Afk-Cgbs-Sg7
```

Desired output is a string array:

```
[Wsg-Fs] A A A Cgbs Sg7 [Wwg+s-Fs] A A Afk Cgbs Sg7
```

If I split the input string with `-` as delimiter, the string within square brackets also gets split.

How do I split the string such that `-` within square bracket should be ignored?

I could find some similar posts trying to ignore delimiter enclosed in quotes, however I have not been able to apply those solution to my problem.

Any suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This post shows how to do it with CSV files having quotation marks; I imagine it could be adapted for square brackets:  http://www.kimgentes.com/worshiptech-web-tools-page/2008/10/14/regex-pattern-for-parsing-csv-files-with-embedded-commas-dou.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming there are no nested square brackets, you can use the following to only match `-` characters that are outside of square brackets:

```
-(?![^\[]*\])
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/sX5hZ2

This uses a negative lookahead, with the logic that if there is a closing square bracket before any opening square brackets, then the `-` that we tried to match is inside of brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Resurrecting this ancient question to offer another solution, since the current one only checks that a splitting `-` is not followed by a `]`, which does not guarantee that it is enclosed in brackets.

```
\[[^\]]*\]|(-)
```

Then splitting on Group 1 (see the Group 1 captures in the bottom right panel of the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vL2gD0))

To split on Group 1, we first replace Group 1 with something distinctive, such as `SPLIT_HERE`, then we split on SPLIT_HERE

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
class Program
{
static void Main() {
string s1 = @"[Wsg-Fs]-A-A-A-Cgbs-Sg7-[Wwg+s-Fs]-A-A-Afk-Cgbs-Sg7";
var myRegex = new Regex(@"\[[^\]]*\]|(-)");
var group1Caps = new StringCollection();

string replaced = myRegex.Replace(s1, delegate(Match m) {
if (m.Groups[1].Value == "") return m.Groups[0].Value;
else return "SPLIT_HERE";
});

string[] splits = Regex.Split(replaced,"SPLIT_HERE");
foreach (string split in splits) Console.WriteLine(split);

Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();

} // END Main
} // END Program
```

Here's a full working [online demo](http://ideone.com/B0rAZR)

**Reference**

[How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

[How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)