# A regexp in Javascript that will capture a word only if it is NOT inside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

> This is very sad, and this is [very sad] and [test;very sad]

What I need, is a regexp that will capture ‘very sad’ only if it is not inside brackets. I tried something like this:

```
[^\[](very sad)[^\]]
```

But it doesn’t seem to work if ‘very sad’ is at the beginning of the string, and when it does – it captures some extra spaces around the string, as can be seen here:

https://regex101.com/r/zwgeXg/1

Comment: A usual workaround is `very sad(?![^\][]*])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew or `very sad(?![^[]*])`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, anyway, I cannot find the exact duplicate. A solution is just to match anything inside square brackets and then match what OP needs in other contexts. `/\[[^\][]*]|(very sad)/g`, and then use some code to apply the necessary changes.

Comment: or see [Regex for matching a character, but not when it's enclosed in square bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204657/regex-for-matching-a-character-but-not-when-its-enclosed-in-square-bracket)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew

Thanks, your answer as well as RokoC.Buljan answer seem to work but if don’t mind me asking - are they equivalent? Looking at the regexp101, I can’t seem to understand the difference…

Comment: They are not equivalent. But will work for this concrete case.